# не могу обратиться к NEW в триггере

Tags: mysql

Таблица Goals состоит из полей

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Goal_id | Game_id | Player_id | Goal_time |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Таблица Games состоит из полей

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Game_id | Team_1_id | Team_2_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

В триггере при добавлении новой записи в таблицу Goals нужно получить из новой записи `Goals.Game_id`  записи   `Team_1_id` и `Team_2_id`. 
Написал запрос для нахождения id первой комманды

```
SELECT g.Team_1_id INTO N FROM games g, goals g1
  WHERE g1.Game_id= g.Game_id 
 AND g1.Game_id= NEW.g1.Game_id
GROUP BY g.Team_1_id;
```

при доавлении выдает ошибку

> Unknown column 'NEW.g1.Game_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Просто `NEW.Game_id`. *Написал запрос для нахождения id первой комманды* Запрос делает совершенно иное.

Comment: Я хотел найти id  первой команды из новой добавленной игры. что не правильно?

Comment: NEW содержит информацию только одной, текущей записи. Использовать в запросе ту же таблицу на которую пишется триггер при этом не рекомендуется. Что то мне подсказывает, что `select Team_1_id from games where game_id=NEW.game_id` более чем достаточно

Comment: все подошло, спаибо